# connecting to a live spark application from a remote system

Tags: apache-spark

I have a spark application deployed on the cluster. I want to run the application with some variables passed from another application running on a remote machine. For example I will pass a query string from the application running remotely and I want my spark application to listen to that and process the query and give back the response to the caller.

Is it possible to do with any library or feature provided by spark.

Answer (score 1):

A Spark application is like any other application. An application can take remote commands in a million different ways. Perhaps most common is to make the application an HTTP server. Then it can be remote controlled through a web interface or a REST API.

If you're using Spark through Scala, the Play Framework is a popular option.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for an option where I can submit a spark application to the cluster once and from a java program I will be able to submit jobs to that application and get the results. Then I can call it from my HTTP Server app via a Java call. The variables to the application could be passed from the Java program.  For example I want to do a time based  query from a database and want to do a group by of the returned results. I should be able to pass the date range to the already submitted application and execute the logic and get results.

Comment: There's no built-in support for that, but nothing stops you from implementing it yourself.